# Compute $\iint_{|z|\le 1} \frac{1}{|z-a|} dz\wedge d\bar z$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there an explicit formula in terms of a fixed real number $a>0$ for the following integral?

$$\iint_{|z|\le 1} \frac{1}{|z-a|} dz\wedge d\bar z$$

We may need to consider the two cases when $a$ is greater than $1$ or not.

Here I use the complex variable $z=x+iy$ in $\mathbb C$, but it is equivalent to an integral with the usual coordinates in $\mathbb R^2$ as follows:
$$
\iint_{|x|^2+|y|^2\le 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}} dx dy
$$

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates? This is standard when $a=0$ or $a=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but for a general $a$, I tend to believe there is no explicit formula. But I am not sure.

Comment: Work it out. I believe you will get an elliptic integral. That’s reasonably explicit.